# GHCI: how to save state on Prelude repl?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to execute fibonacci on the prelude repl but I'm running into an infinite loop:

```
Prelude> fib 0 = 1
Prelude> fib 1 = 1
Prelude> fib n = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
Prelude>
Prelude> fib 3
<loops infinitely...>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write a multi-line declaration in GHCi, you need to wrap it in `:{ :}` so that Haskell knows to evaluate the whole definition at the same time. What you're doing right now is defining a function `fib` where `fib 0` is `1`, then defining a new function `fib` that shadows the first one where `fib 1` is `1`, and then defining a third function shadowing the second one, which is the only definitition that Haskell sees when it tries to execute `fib 3`. The solution is to tell GHCi that this is all the same definition, which is done using the `:{` command:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fib 0 = 1
Prelude| fib 1 = 1
Prelude| fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> fib 3
3
```

It's worth noting that implementing `fib` as a recursive function like this is bound to be time-inefficient, and it's generally better to define it as a recursive infinite list, like this:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| fib n = fibs !! n
Prelude|    where fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> fib 3
3
```